# Detail in the proof that eigenvectors are orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, transpose

Show that, for a symmetric matrix $\textbf{A}$, if $\textbf{x}_1$ and $\textbf{x}_2$ are two eigenvectors of $\textbf{A}$ such that their respective eigenvalues are distinct and non-zero then $\textbf{x}_1^\top\textbf{x}_2 = 0$

**Solution**

because $\textbf{A}$ is symmetric we know that 
$$
(\textbf{x}_2^\top\textbf{A}\textbf{x}_1)^\top = \textbf{x}_1^\top\textbf{A}\textbf{x}_2
$$
$$
\textbf{x}_1^\top\textbf{A}\textbf{x}_2 = \textbf{x}_2^\top\textbf{A}\textbf{x}_1\tag{1}
$$
from the eigenvalue/eigenvector definition we know that:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{x}_1^\top\textbf{A}\textbf{x}_2 
&= \textbf{x}_1^\top\lambda_2\textbf{x}_2\\
\textbf{x}_2^\top\textbf{A}\textbf{x}_1 
&= \textbf{x}_2^\top\lambda_1\textbf{x}_1
\end{align*}
Hence 
\begin{align*}
\textbf{x}_1^\top\lambda_2\textbf{x}_2&=\textbf{x}_2^\top\lambda_1\textbf{x}_1\\
\implies \lambda_2\textbf{x}_1^\top\textbf{x}_2&=\lambda_1\textbf{x}_2^\top\textbf{x}_1\\
\implies 0&= \lambda_2\textbf{x}_1^\top\textbf{x}_2-\lambda_1\textbf{x}_2^\top\textbf{x}_1\\
&= \lambda_2\textbf{x}_1^\top\textbf{x}_2-\lambda_1\textbf{x}_1^\top\textbf{x}_2\\
&= \underbrace{(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)}_{\ne 0 \text{ by definition}}\textbf{x}_1^\top\textbf{x}_2\\
\implies 0&= \textbf{x}_1^\top\textbf{x}_2 \quad \square
\end{align*}

**My question**

- which property of linear algebra do we have to invoke to justify (1)?

Comment: Where did the words "and non-zero" come from? You didn't use $\lambda_j\ne0$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transpose of a scalar is the same scalar, so we can drop the $\top$ in the left hand side. Then swap LHS and RHS.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever $AB$ is defined we have $(AB)^{T}=B^{T}A^{T}$. Apply this twice to derive 1). [Also $(A^{T})^{T}=A$].

Comment: Alternatively, you can just apply $\cdot^T$ to the whole equation and then flip sides of LHS and RHS (for whatever reason).